# Android Firebase firing onChildChanged on write

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am experiencing unexplained behaviour with the Android ChildEventListener.

I have a ChildEventListener setup on the "game" node with the onChildAdded, onChildChanged and onChildRemoved callbacks setup:

```
aQuery = mDatabase.child(Constants.FIREBASE_DEV_DATA_CHILD).child("aNode").child("game");
```

However, when I write to the "game" node with the following...

```
mDatabase.child(Constants.FIREBASE_DEV_DATA_CHILD).child("aNode").child("game").push().setValue(createGame, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener()
```

... it is firing both the onChildAdded and onChildChanged callbacks. The dataSnapshot is the same for both. I don't understand why that is happening? Shouldn't just the onChildAdded fire when I write?

Comment: What's `createGame`? In general: try to reproduce the problem with a single snippet of code with only hard-coded values. That makes it the easiest for us to see what's going on, or try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: createGame is a custom class with an assortment of Strings, Doubles and LatLng's. I'll try writing a simple string and report back.

Comment: Okay after some testing, it appears to be when I use createGame.created_timestamp = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. If I don't use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP the callback behaves as expected.

Comment: Ah yes, a timestamp would indeed explain (which is why I asked what `createGame` is). See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864974/how-to-use-the-firebase-server-timestamp-to-generate-date-created/37868163#37868163

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, your break down of execution steps in your linked thread makes a lot of sense. I don't quite follow the link you provided as a method of dealing with it though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096128/when-making-a-pojo-in-firebase-can-you-use-servervalue-timestamp/33111791#33111791 - This won't stop the onChildChanged being fired for new writes, will it?