# Firebase - what data type is firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, floating-point, double

I was looking around to find the data type of a `TIMESTAMP`. I looked in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue) but it doesn't mention anything about type.

Are these a `Float` or a `Double` or another type?

```
const currentDate = Date.now();
const timeStamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

This is the way `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` appears inside the RTDB:

[image]

Comment: The `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is for the Firebase Realtime Database, but you tagged with `google-cloud-firestore`. Both have a server-side timestamp sentinel, but it'd be good to know which one you're actually asking about.

Comment: I'll change it, gimme a sec

Comment: I'm more interested in `Date.now()` for the `RTDB`. I thought that they would be the same datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` field is a so-called sentinel value. Upon writing it to the database, it is actually a map: `{ ".sv": "timestamp" }`. But then in the database itself, and when you read a field of this value back, you'll get a regular number (the milliseconds since the epoch).

Depending on your platform, this asymmetrical type can lead to interesting programming challenges. For example, see: [When making a POJO in Firebase, can you use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096128/when-making-a-pojo-in-firebase-can-you-use-servervalue-timestamp)

Comment: when you say a regular number, is the regular number a float or a double? Or is a number in javascript the same as a NSNumber in Obj-c?

Comment: When reading a value back, it's a long number: the number of milliseconds since the epoch.