# I want the value of timestamp in long format iam using ServerValue.Timestamp

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Iam using ServerValue.TimeStamp and upload to firebase using hashmap

`HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
 map.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`

but I need to get the value of TimeStamp in long without upload it to the firebase 
I have tried to cast it to long but always receive ClassCastException

```
        Map<String, Object> currentTime = new HashMap<>();
    currentTime.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    return (long) currentTime.get("timestamp");
```

any help ?!

Comment: Looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658833/firebase-servervalue-timestamp-in-java-data-models-objects

Comment: yes I tried this but the same problem ClassCastException @ScaryWombat

Comment: There is no way to get the long value from the Firebase server, without first sending the string value to that server. See [Osama's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744398/retrieve-servervalue-timestamp-from-firebase-in-android-app-when-data-is-sent) or [Lyla's more advanced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096128/when-making-a-pojo-in-firebase-can-you-use-servervalue-timestamp).

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me when i do small change in model class by replacing

```
Map<String , String> timestamp;
```

with

```
Object timestamp;
```

as Object class is the parent of all classes in java so any subclass will work fine with it as when you save the value in firebase it's ok and when retrieve value all just you need is to cast this object to Long

here's my Model i used

```
public class UserModel {
private String name , phone, email, birthDate, userType, address;
Object timestamp;

// for firebase retrieving data
public UserModel() {
}

public UserModel(String name, String phone, String email, String birthDate, String userType, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.address = address;
    //get Date from firebase server automatic
    this.timestamp =  ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
     String data = " user name" + this.name+" , user Address : "
             +this.address+" , user phone "+this.phone+" , user email : "+this.email
             +" , user birthdate : "+this.birthDate+" , user type : "+this.userType
             + " , registered time "+this.timestamp;
    return data;
}

/* public String getLoginDate() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'");
    Date date = new Date(si)
    return ;
}*/
}
```

> and i uploaded it in firebase successufly

[image: firebase image]

> and here is the reslt i recieved when download data from firebase

[image: data after download from firebase]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and i solved it.hope this will help you :D

```
    String key = mDatabase.push().getKey();mDatabase.child(ke).setValue(mMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        mDatabase.push().child("date").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                                    }
                                });
mDatabase.child(ke).child("date").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```