# Save current time when node is created in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, datetime, firebase-realtime-database

I am making MovieList App. Store all the data of movie in Firebase. Now i want to store the current time in firebase when new node of movie is created. And then in MovieList, I want to display the difference between tim like '1 minute ago' or '1 day ago' etc..

The main point is i want the difference between those two times.
Can anyone help to acheive this.Thanx

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658833/firebase-servervalue-timestamp-in-java-data-models-objects

Comment: In addition, i want the difference between that time and current time to display in cardview with that specific movie.