# How to use the Firebase server timestamp to generate date created?

Tags: android, firebase, timestamp, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, the Google's version of `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` returns `{".sv":"timestamp"}` which is used as a directive for Firebase to fill that field with the server timestamp once you save the data to the Firebase server.

When you create your data on the client side however, you don't have the actual timestamp to play with yet (ie. use as the creation date). You only will have an access to the timestamp after the initial save and consequent retrieval, which - I imagine - is sometimes too late and not very elegant.

---

**Before Google:**

*Update: Ignore this section as it is incorrect - I misunderstood the examples. `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` always returned the `{".sv":"timestamp"}`.*

As far as I understand in pre-google Firebase there seemed to be a server-generated timestamp available that allowed you to acquire the actual timestamp:

```java
import com.firebase.client.ServerValue;
ServerValue.TIMESTAMP // eg. 1466094046
```

([ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33111791/3508719), [ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512747/3508719))

---

**Questions:**

1. Is such save/retrieval the only way to get the server-generated creation date on my model instances?
2. If yes can you propose a method of implementing such pattern?
3. Am I understanding correctly ServerValue.TIMESTAMP has changed with Google's acquisition of Firebase? *Update: No, @FrankvanPuffelen replied that nothing's changed during acquisition.*

---

**Note:**

I'm not considering using `new Date()` on client side as I've been reading it's not safe, though please share your thoughts if you think different.

Comment: *firebaser here* Nothing changed in the way we generate the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` since we joined Google. Code that worked before, will continue to work. If you have code that doesn't work, add the minimal code that reproduces the problem to your question please.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I misunderstood the old examples then, thanks. `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` always returned `{".sv":"timestamp"}`. I'm not referring to code that doesn't work though, just a theoretical question on how to correctly use that server timestamp to work with *date created*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you use the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` constant in a write operation, you're saying that the Firebase Database server should determine the correct timestamp when it executes the write operation.

Let's say we run this code:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue()); 
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

This will execute as follows:

1. you attach a listener
2. you write a value with `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`
3. the Firebase client immediate fires a value event with an approximation of the timestamp it will write on the server
4. your code prints that value
5. the write operation gets sent to the Firebase servers
6. the Firebase servers determine the actual timestamp and write the value to the database (assuming no security rules fail)
7. the Firebase server send the actual timestamp back to the client
8. the Firebase client raises a value event for the actual value
9. your code prints that value

If you're using `ChildEventListener` instead of a `ValueEventListener`, then the client will call `onChildAdded` in step 3 and `onChildChanged` in step 8.

Nothing changed in the way we generate the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` since Firebase joined Google. Code that worked before, will continue to work. That also means that the [first answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096128/when-making-a-pojo-in-firebase-can-you-use-servervalue-timestamp/33111791#33111791) is a valid way to handle it.

Comment: is that possible add a modification on ServerValue.TimeStamp for example I want to make it as a Date(). after that a query will orderbychilld such as today, tomorrow

Comment: @mehmet did you find a way? I am storing "scores" based on the server timestamp, and I need to get the "scores" stored in the last 48 hours; because the local time of each device is different

Comment: Unfortunately nope

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing it a bit differently.

**Solution 1: `push()` method in POJO**

As I don't want to clutter my POJOs with strange getters or properties, I'm just defining a `push()` method inside my POJOs which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Pushes a new instance to the DB.
 * 
 * @param parentNode `DatabaseReference` to the parent node this object shall be attached to
 */
fun push(parentNode: DatabaseReference) {
    parentNode
        .push()
        .apply {
            setValue(this@Pojo)
            child(Pojo.CREATED_AT_KEY).setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
        }
}
```

Then I can simply create an instance of the POJO and call `push()` on it which properly populates the creation time property.

*This definitely makes the POJO a little less plain and involves logic a POJO shouldn't know about. However using `@Exclude` annotations and/or casts as outlined in some of the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096128/when-making-a-pojo-in-firebase-can-you-use-servervalue-timestamp?lq=1) also requires knowledge of the storing mechanism.*

**Solution 2: Helper or `DatabaseReference` extension (Kotlin)**

To overcome this you can of course also just create a `pushTask(task: Task)` method in a helper or - if using Kotlin - an extension method to e.g. `DatabaseReference` which could look like this:

```
fun DatabaseReference.push(pojo: Pojo) {
    push()
    .apply {
        setValue(pojo)
        child(Pojo.CREATED_AT_KEY).setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
    }
}
```

Looking at it now I come to think that I actually like the second approach more (*if* I have Kotlin at my disposal - I don't like helpers). But this is probably just a matter of taste. ;)