# How does Firebase ServerValue.TIMESTAMP work in this situation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864974/how-to-use-the-firebase-server-timestamp-to-generate-date-created/37868163#37868163) about `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` that the `ValueEventListener` will fire twice with first the local time and then with server time.. My question is will that only happen if the code look like this using `setValue`:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue()); 
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

Or will it also happen if the call is a `updateChildren` like this, notice the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

```
Map<String, Object> someMap = new HashMap<>();
someMap.put("id", 239231);
someMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
someMap.put("name", "some name");
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("someKey", someMap);
mFirebase.updateChildren(childUpdates, new CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

    }
});
```

*UPDATE*

Here´s what I try to do.
In the [Firebase code lab for Friendly Chat app(friendlychat).](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) I replace the send chat message code that look like this:

```
FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new 
               FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                               mUsername,
                               mPhotoUrl,
                               null /* no image */);
       mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)
               .push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
```

with an `childUpdates` instead like this:

```
        final String pushKeyAddress = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().getKey();
                Map<String, Object> someMap = new HashMap<>();
                someMap.put("text", mMessageEditText.getText().toString());
                someMap.put("name", mUsername);
                someMap.put("photoUrl", mPhotoUrl);
                someMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates.put(MESSAGES_CHILD.concat("/").concat(pushKeyAddress), someMap);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        System.out.println(databaseError);
                    }

                });
```

And I see the `CompletionListener` `onComplete` only fires once and not twice as I would expect since I use the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864974/how-to-use-the-firebase-server-timestamp-to-generate-date-created/37868163#37868163) (which you link in the question) explains what happens in "in a write operation". The same thing will happen for either a `setValue()` and an `updateChildren()`.

Comment: in my `updateChildren` example code above I have one HashMap `someMap`. What if there is 2 like `someMap1` and `someMap2` targeting dif locations in Firebase-databas, and they both have a `("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`, will that make the onComplete() trigger four times??

Comment: Each write of `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` will follow the same flow as in my linked answer. Is that not the behavior you see when you run the code?

Comment: I must do something wrong the `updateChildren` `onComplete(..)` only fires once but the `("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)` key in Firebase is set ok. This is not a problem I just wanted to understand this. I set a breakpoints and even do `System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue()); ` Maybe it´s because  ` setPersistenceEnabled(true) `  ..mmm

Comment: I update my Q with specifics please have a look and say what you think