# I wanted to convert firebase timestamp to UTC timeview in react native

Tags: datetime, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, unix-timestamp

i have been searching for solution for 2 days now
here is my code

```
saveData = () =>{
    let servertime = Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    this.itemsRef.push({name:this.state.text,date:servertime});
    var s = new Date(parseInt(servertime)).toUTCString();
    alert(s);
  }
```

but alert return me with invalid value
i try to put an unix interger directly like this

```
saveData = () =>{
        let servertime = Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
        this.itemsRef.push({name:this.state.text,date:servertime});
        var s = new Date(1509004701954).toUTCString();
        alert(s);
      }
```

and it work well
why cant i get the same result?

Comment: `Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a placeholder constant that serves as an instruction for the sever to replace it will the actual sever time when it's received.

Comment: so how do i need to change?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37868163/6680611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a constant that represents the object `{ ".sv": "timestamp" }`. Firebase uses it to automatically put in the current timestamp.

You need to push the data, then grab the snapshot and read the 'date' back:

```
saveData = () => {
   this.itemsRef.push(
       {
           name:this.state.text, 
           date:Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
       }).then((snapshot) => {
           var s = new Date(parseInt(snapshot.val().date)).toUTCString();
           alert(s);
       }
 }
```