# How to correctly display the date of a list from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model class which looks like this:

```
public class ListModel {
    private String listName;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date date;

    public ListModel() {}    
    public ListModel(String listName) {this.listName = listName;}

    //setters and getters
}
```

This is how I add a `list` to database:

```
 ListModel listModel = new ListModel(listName);
 listsRef.document(listId).set(listModel);
```

When I look into the database, my date looks like this:

[image]

To display the `name` and the `date` of the list, I'm using a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and a `RecyclerView`. The problem is when I add a list, the name is displayed instantly but the date is displayed first as `null` and only after one or two seconds is displayed correctly.

I know that the date is generated server side, but how can I display the date correctly from the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no way to immediately show the timestamp. The server-side timestamp is only generated on the server, and is `null` until the response from the server comes back.

There is work under way to make the client estimate the timestamp straight away. Once that is released, you'll get two events (similar to [how the Firebase Realtime Database works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864974/how-to-use-the-firebase-server-timestamp-to-generate-date-created)): the first event contains a local estimate of the timestamp, the second event contains the actual confirmed timestamp from the server.

Comment: Thanks again Frank!