# How to get date in chatting application,

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I will take date from the system `(local date in UTC)` then, the problem occurs when the user changes the date, if I will use server date time then I can not able to send a message when I am offline,  this application is developed in android using firebase `real-time DB`

Comment: use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: no i have implemented this before but not working

Comment: not working ? any errors

Answer (score 0):

### [**`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue#TIMESTAMP)

```
public static final Map<String, String> TIMESTAMP
```

Also: [Google Play services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue#TIMESTAMP)

A placeholder value for auto-populating the **current timestamp** (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the `Firebase Database` servers.

**`Example`**

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37868163/9909365

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue()); 
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

**`Extra`**

### [**`Handling Latency`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?authuser=0)

**Server Timestamps**

The Firebase Realtime Database servers provide a mechanism to insert timestamps generated on the server as data. This feature, combined with `onDisconnect`, provides an easy way to reliably make note of the time at which a Realtime `Database client disconnected`:

```
//Java
DatabaseReference userLastOnlineRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/joe/lastOnline");
userLastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);


//Kotlin
val userLastOnlineRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/joe/lastOnline")
userLastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
```